How add `Startup` in `Device` in `Manage Run-Time Enviroment` in Keil uvision 5?
I just started learning STM32 and decided to work in keil uvision 5. However, when I start a project, I can't select Startup in Devices. Instead, I have CubeMX there.
I installed the latest version of keil uvision 5.41.0.0 from the official website.

After that, I went to the package installer and installed the following packages (I have Nucleo-F446RE).

After that, I went to keil and created a new project. However, when I started connecting components, I should have seen Startup in Device, not CubeMX. What's the problem?

I tried to install Startup in Device, but there is only CubeMX. Before that I installed all the necessary packages via the package installer.

In the later updates of the Keil::STM32F4xx_DFP the option for device->start up has been removed. You can remove the latest version and install a previous version and it should work. GL

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Can you tell me how old the version is required?

According to www.keil.arm.com/packs/stm32f4xx_dfp-keil/versions/, it was removed in Version 3.0.0. any version before that should include the start-up option.

Yes, it worked, thank you! I'd like to add that it worked for me on KeiluVision 5.24.2.0 and Keil::STM32F4xx_DFP 2.4.0. It's installed directly in the package installer

As already written above, you need to roll back the version. It worked for me on Keil uVision 5.24.2.0 and Keil::STM32F4xx_DFP 2.4.0. It is installed directly in the package installer after uVision installation. Screenshot
